# WPF - There is no effect in the Margins set when there is a scrollviewer

Tags: wpf, margin, scrollviewer

In my .xaml file, I have something like in the following.

```
    <TextBlock   Text="......"   ..... Margin="5,3,4,2"/>
    <ScrollViewer  Margin="2,3,7,9">
              <TextBlock Margin=3,6,5,7">
    </ScrollViewer>
```

There is no effect in the margins set for above controls. No effect at all. Is it because of the ScrollViewer which contains the second TextBlock ?

Comment: code seems vaild, and working in simple application.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment for each element with a margin like this

```
VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,20"
```

Chances are the margins are working but since you don't have a fixed position for the elements it might be hard to notice the difference especially since your margins are on the smaller side.